# Navigation back not working good from browser back button

Tags: flutter

I noticed that navigation in my Flutter Web app not working well if I'm using back button from browser.

For example:

1. Go from home page to first page
2. Go from first page to second page
3. Coming back to the first page
4. I cannot back to home page, until I click on any place on screen.

It only happens in Flutter Web. In Android app it's working fine

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),


      title: 'Genistree',

    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.yellowAccent,
        child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
         // Get.to(FirstPage());

          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => FirstPage(),
            ),
          );


        }, child: Text("Go to 1st page"),

        ),),

    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {

         // Get.to(SecondPage());
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => SecondPage(),
            ),
          );

        }, child: Text("Go to 2st page"),

        ),),);
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bunch of solutions, but nothing worked for me except this one.
It remembers the stack's navigation.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(GetMaterialApp.router(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    defaultTransition: Transition.fade,
    getPages: AppPages.pages,
    routerDelegate: AppRouterDelegate(),
  ));
}

abstract class Routes {
  static const homePage = '/';
  static const firstPage = '/firstPage';
  static const secondPage = '/secondPage';
}

class AppRouterDelegate extends GetDelegate {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result),
      pages: currentConfiguration != null
          ? [currentConfiguration!.currentPage!]
          : [GetNavConfig.fromRoute(Routes.homePage)!.currentPage!],
    );
  }
}

abstract class AppPages {
  static final pages = [
    GetPage(
      name: Routes.homePage,
      page: () => const HomePage(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: Routes.firstPage,
      page: () => const FirstPage(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: Routes.secondPage,
      page: () => const SecondPage(),
    ),
  ];
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.yellowAccent,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => Get.rootDelegate.toNamed(Routes.firstPage),
          child: const Text("Go to 1st page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => Get.rootDelegate.toNamed(Routes.secondPage),
          child: const Text("Go to 2st page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know this solutuon but in this PopScope doesnt'work

Comment: The problem was the Navigation stack did not store the first page, as we navigate to the 3rd page. Now it's working fine with this approach. 
run the snippet with  flutter run -d chrome.
Please give me details, which part is not working.!

Comment: I mean, It'working in this version, but if You add PopScope widget to SecondPage, widget is not working. I some cases I want to block back button.

Comment: So, The problem you were facing as you stated in the question body. 3. Coming back to the first page 4. I cannot back to home page, until I click on any place on screen. Is solved? Or you are facing problem with that also?

Comment: Yes, this is ok right now but it caused new problem

Comment: Can you please describe the scenario clearly so that I can provide another solution for you?

Comment: Just wrap Scaffold widget in "SecondPage" to the PopScope widget with option canPop: false. It should disable possibility return from SecondPage by clicking back button.
But I can return. Without GetX this actually works.

Comment: Okay then remove get from pubspec.yaml

Comment: Yes, but then navigation navigation will not work properly again. I'm getting to that each of these solutions (GetX or without GetX) has its problems.
Flutter Web at these moment has serious problem with nvaigation in more complex apps. GetX maybe solve these but creates new problems (like this with PopScope)

Answer (score -1):

This issue might be related to the way Flutter handles routing and navigation on the web. You can try using WillPopScope widget to handle back button behavior explicitly in your Flutter web app.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's bad that I have to handle in this simply case. In my app I have a lot o pages that I want only back to previous without any complex logic:/